# ContextListener Class Not Found

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, servlets

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.10
Aug 23, 2023 11:49:10 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader setClassPath
INFO: Unknown loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@22d8cfe0 class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader
Aug 23, 2023 11:49:11 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader setClassPath
INFO: Unknown loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@22d8cfe0 class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader
Aug 23, 2023 11:49:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.linkdom.intercom.listener.ContextListene
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.linkdom.intercom.listener.ContextListene
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4588)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5149)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Aug 23, 2023 11:49:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Aug 23, 2023 11:49:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Aug 23, 2023 11:49:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Intercome] startup failed due to previous errors
```

why i am getting this issue , even though this class is available

Comment: There is far too little information here to answer this. What is in your `web.xml` (seems like a type `ContextListene` which should be `ContextListener` (notice a missing `r` at the end)).